# How to position cursor precisely on an iPhone running iOS 9.3.x?

Tags: keyboard, ios

So I'm trying to find ways where I can easily control cursor position on my iPhone.

```
example.

I type the following phrase/sentence on Messages: I have a pet cuck.
```

I want to position the cursor just after the u in the work "cuck" and correct the spelling. Any ideas on it came be done --without-- resorting to jailbreak (which is not even possible on my version anyway).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press on the word.

You will then get a round magnifier covering the text. You can then move your finger and the cursor will move by character

Comment: @mrjayviper two other solutions to this, in addition to Mark's: 1. on an iPhone 6s with 3D Touch you can move the cursor along by dragging your finger left/right on the spacebar while pressing down hard. 2. download a keyboard app like Fleksy or Go Keyboard, both of which you can use the trick from step 1 on without needing 3D touch.